# Single word that encompasses for strong, robust, flexible?

Tags: single-word-requests

First post here but I'm wondering if there is a word that encompasses `strong, robust, flexible, powerful`? I was thinking of zenith personally, but can anybody think of similar words?

Comment: I'm not sure what zenith has to do with any of those words - it's just the top, the highest point, straight upwards, the opposite of nadir.

Comment: Not too many words that could mean both strong and flexible!  Zenith may not be related at all.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "robust."  If you are describing a person, "agile" is a broader description than most people realize.  You should really tell us what you want to describe with your adjective!

Comment: Depending on the context: Vigorous! Dynamic! Effective! Or now that I'm over fifty: young!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a SWR requesting a synonym for widely disparate words.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *"ultimate"* would suit your needs better than "zenith". As descriptors, how about: *unbreakable*, *impervious*, *Herculean*, *incorruptible*?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a word that covers all that adjectives, and as suggested in the comments [zenith](http://efficacious%20(%CB%8C%C9%9Bf%C9%AA%CB%88ke%C9%AA%CA%83%C9%99s)%20adj%201.%20capable%20of%20or%20successful%20in%20producing%20an%20intended%20result;%20effective%20as%20a%20means,%20remedy,%20etc%20[C16:%20from%20Latin%20effic%C4%81x%20powerful,%20efficient,%20from%20efficere%20to%20achieve;%20see%20effect])  is not related to them.

I think [efficacious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Efficacious) may come close to what you are looking for as it suggest the idea of power (see etymology) and adaptability:

> - capable of or successful in producing an intended result; effective as a means, remedy, etc.
> - (from Latin efficāx powerful, efficient, from efficere to achieve)

(TFD)

Answer (score 0):

On the face, [*strong*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strong) and [*powerful*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/powerful) seem to have the most in common, while [*flexible*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flexible) seems to be the outlier. *Strong*, *powerful* and *flexible* are all listed as *[synonyms of robust](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/robust?s=t)*, suggesting it has the broadest semantic field to include the other three words considered:

[*Robust*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/robust) would be a decent choice:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 (Of an object) **sturdy** in construction:
>
> 1.1 **Strong** and healthy; vigorous:
>
> 1.2 (Of a system, organization, etc.) able to **withstand** or overcome adverse conditions:
>
> 1.3 Uncompromising and forceful:
>
> OED
>
> [Origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=robust&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> 1540s, from Middle French *robuste* (14c.) and directly from Latin
>   *robustus* "***strong*** and hardy," literally "*as **strong** as oa*k," originally
>   "*oaken*,"
>
> from *robur*, *robus* "*hard timber, **strength***," also "a special kind of
>   *oak*," named for its reddish heartwood,
>
> from Latin **ruber** "*red*" (related to robigo "rust"),
>
> from PIE *reudh- (see red (adj.1)).
>
> Etymonline.com **Emphasis** mine

The idea of strength is clearly present, and the ability to withstand adverse conditions connects to flexibility.

[*Vigorous*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vigorous) arises from the definition of *robust*:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 **Strong**, healthy, and full of **energy**:
>
> 1.1 Characterized by or involving physical **strength**, effort, or **energy**:
>
> OED
>
> [Origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vigorous&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> c.1300 (early 13c. as a surname), from Anglo-French *vigrus*, Old
>   French *vigoros* "***strong***, ***robust***, ***powerful***" (12c.,
>   Modern French vigoreux),
>
> from Medieval Latin *vigorosus*,
>
> from Latin *vigere* "be ***lively***, *flourish*, *thrive*"
>
> (see *[vigor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vigor&allowed_in_frame=0)*)
>
> c.1300, "*physical strength, energy in an activity*,"
>
> from Anglo-French *vigour*, Old French *vigor* "*force*, *strength*"
>   (Modern French *vigueur*),
>
> from Latin *vigorem* (nominative *vigor*) "*liveliness, activity,
>   force*,"
>
> from *vigere* "*be lively, flourish, thrive*,"
>
> from PIE root *weg- (2) "*be lively or active*"

Again, *strong* is clearly present in the meaning of *vigorous*. *Powerful* is implied in the exertion of *energy* and *force* in *activity*. The notion *lively* accepts *flexibility* comfortably with its implication  of *resilient thriving*.

Moving away from a definitive approach, the **effect** of an entity with the four qualities could be described as *[dynamic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dynamic)*:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 (Of a process or system) characterized by constant **change**, activity, or **progress**: a dynamic economy
>
> 2.0 (Of a person) positive in attitude and **full of energy** and new ideas:
>
> [Origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dynamic&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> 1817 as a term in philosophy; 1827 in the sense "pertaining to ***force***
>   *producing* ***motion***" (the opposite of static),
>
> from French *dynamique* introduced by German mathematician Gottfried
>   Leibnitz (1646-1716) in 1691
>
> from Greek *dynamikos* "***powerful***,"
>
> from *dynamis* "***power***,"
>
> from *dynasthai* "to be *able*, to have *power*, be *strong* enough," which is
>   of unknown origin.
>
> The figurative sense of "active, potent, energetic" is from 1856 (in
>   Emerson).

*Powerful* is present by connection to the Greek *dynamikos*, and strong by connection to *powerful*. The emphasis on *active change* captures the essence of *robust flexibility*.

Of course anything that is *powerful*, *strong*, *robust* and *flexible* would be *[effective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/effective)* in most endeavors.

Answer (score -1):

Are you describing a person or a thing? If it's a person, how about "protean"? It's a bit florid, perhaps? The word comes from Proteus, a greek god associated with change and water, so it implies both versatility and great ability.

Comment: What does *protean* mean?

Comment: . able to do many different things; versatile.
"Shostakovich was a remarkably protean composer, one at home in a wide range of styles"

-google